# How to write the payload in request

Tags: python-3.x

```
import request
payload = {
    "pagination" : "{offset: 0, limit: 5},…}"
}

pending_schedule = s.post("https://xxxx.com",data=payload)
print(pending_schedule)
```

[image: Request Payload]

Is there any solution to awrite request payload based on image